# Pheatmap: Make hierarchical clustering on full matrix but only display subset of rows

Tags: r, pheatmap

I have a gene expression data set and want to show a heatmap of **some** of the genes. First, I want to make hierarchical clustering based on all genes, and create a dendrogram, and then create a heatmap on a subset of those genes. In explicit, the heatmap will have same columns as the dendrogram already created, but show less rows. I have tried to use the code below, but it seems that pheatmap re-orders the clusters based on the reduced matrix.

```
# Random data

full_mat <- matrix(rgamma(1000, shape = 1) * 5, ncol = 50)
reduced_mat <- full_mat[1:5,]

# Function to calculate distances on full-matrix and make dendrogram
cl_cb <- function(hcl, mat){
    # Recalculate manhattan distances for reorder method
    dists <- dist(full_mat, method = "manhattan")

    # Perform reordering according to OLO or GW method
    hclust_olo <- reorder(hcl, dists, method="GW")
    return(hclust_olo)
}

# Only display the reduced matrix (same columns but fewer rows)
p <- pheatmap(reduced_mat, 
         show_rownames=TRUE, 
         show_colnames = TRUE,
         cluster_cols=T,
         cluster_rows=F,
         scale = "none",
         clustering_callback = cl_cb
         )
```

I have tried to set `cluster_cols = F`but then no dendogram or re-ordering is made at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the function `heatmap.2` instead. Install it if you don't already have it.

After this, run the following:

```
 heatmap.2(reduced_mat, dendrogram = "both", labRow=row.names(reduced_mat), 
                        labCol=colnames(reduced_mat), Colv = FALSE, Rowv = FALSE)

#If you want to only show row or col dendrogram, change dendrogram = "both" to dendrogram = "column" (or "row")
```

It will still produce a dendrogram based on the subsetted data set however, it should not change the order of the matrix used. If I understand correctly, this is what you want.

If you provide a reproducible example, using `dput()`, I could try it out myself.

Maybe what you could do, if you are set on doing this, is to create the heatmap, keep the ordering of the rows and cols, do not create a second dendrogram and instead save the heatmap as an image, this can be done with the following:

```
dev.copy(jpeg,filename="plot.jpg")
dev.off ()
```

Do the same with your original heatmap, crop out the part of the dendrogram you are interested in, and paste it in photoshop or paint to the second heatmap image created.

However, as mentioned in my comment, this is not a "true" dendrogram of the subsetted dataset, rather, a "snippet" of the original heatmap.

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Thanks! Didn't try yet, but based on your description this will produce a new dendrogram. I want to use the same dendrogram as the one that is produced on the full matrix. I.e the clustering should be based on the full matrix, whereas the heat map function just plots the expression of each gene.

Comment: Ok I understand. I honestly don't know if what you are asking for is possible, because then you are not creating a "true" dendrogram from the data provided.

Comment: Just provided a workaround to your problem by editing the original post ^